# Error in rep(space, max_width) : invalid 'times' argument; in one column

Tags: r, twitter, error-handling, rep

I'm working on two data frames which contain tweet data from two different accounts. The first data frame is working on this twitter account and returns a data frame in my R console.

```
baudet_tweets <- userTimeline("thierrybaudet", n = 3200, includeRts = TRUE)
baudet_tweets_df <- tbl_df(map_df(baudet_tweets, as.data.frame))
```

However, the same code for a different twitter account gives me the error:

```
klaver_tweets <- userTimeline("jesseklaver", n = 3200, includeRts = TRUE)
klaver_tweets_df <- tbl_df(map_df(klaver_tweets, as.data.frame))
```

`Error in rep(space, max_width) : invalid 'times' argument`

I think it's the text column because when I filter out`select(klaver_tweets_df, text)` the text column the code works. But I need the `text` column for textanalysis... I find it strange that the `text` column of `baudet_tweets_df` just works. My code is not really reproducible but here is an image of the df because I CAN `View(klaver_tweets_df). Maybe only`klaver_tweets_df` contains emoticons? If so how can I remove them?

[image: df$text klaver]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the emoji's did the trick!

```
klaver_tweets_df$text <- gsub("[^\x01-\x7F]", "", klaver_tweets_df$text)
```